Asp.net Core Razor Pages, agregar un archivo C# al _Layout.cshtml
quería preguntar si se podría agregar un archivo c# al _Layout.cshtml. Les pongo en contexto, estoy realizando una migración de .NET Framework 4.6.1 al .NET 6, y anteriormente en el .Net framework se utilizaba el Main.master con su archivo c# incluido, ahora para esta migración el main.master seria el _Layout.cshtml pero este no tiene archivo c#, queria saber el procedimiento que se debe realizar en este caso, porque esa logica debe estar en la nueva version. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Tienes 2 tecnologías con paradigmas diferentes. Si pudieras hacer una migración directa de la una a la otra, es que no serían diferentes. Entonces, no pretendas hacer todo tal cual como lo tenías antes, para eso te quedas con lo viejo. Pero para responderte, creo que en el caso específico del layout no es posible anexar un code behind, lo cual si es posible para otros archivos .cshtml en esos casos basta con crear un archivo de igual nombre con extensión  .cshtml.cs.

Estás utilizando 2 tecnologías completamente diferentes, con formas de trabajo diferentes. No existe una manera de migrarlo de manera sencilla, para hacer esto debes de realizar una programación extra para mover todo lo de C# a un controlador nuevo para la aplicación de .NET Framework
